# Does the aura color in Grand Prix Story modify its effectiveness for different actions?

Tags: grand-prix-story

In [Grand Prix Story](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.kairosoft.android.paddock_en) the drivers will at different times enter what is called "Aura Time", during which they are surrounded by a colored aura. Performing most any action (research, upgrade, train, parts install, etc) with that driver will trigger the aura and increase the effectiveness of the action. So far I have seen two colors of aura occur on the same driver (purple and white, and not at the same time).

I am curious as to whether or not the color of the aura affects different actions differently, (i.e. maybe white is more effective at training and purple is better for increasing your qualifier lap).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Auras give you a guaranteed amount, when performing an action (improving a part/car), and also help you when racing.

They are ranked in the following order:

1. blue
2. red
3. silver
4. gold

The values change depending on the action, but for improving a car, it should be 25 (or 30) for the best aura, and then -5 when using a worse aura, so silver would be 20, red 15...

Comment: If you can find a reference that'd be great.

Comment: @Xantec Rewritten, this should be much more precise.